# Can I use a USB drive of Ubuntu created on Mac with a PC?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, usb-boot

I am trying to create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu with my iMac as a holiday present for my brother, who is on a PC.

Will my bootable USB work on his computer if I create it on my Mac?

Comment: It should work as long as it isn't formatted as a HFS partition, FAT32 and NTFS will work fine.

Comment: ok, just making sure. the ubuntu website is about as clear as mud about these things.

Comment: If you've downloaded an image from the Ubuntu web site and copied it direct to the key drive, following the instructions to make a bootable key drive, then yes, it will work.